# Easy to understand and follow books on jQuery and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know your opinion of a good jQuery and JavaScript book. There are just too many of them [when I try to search]. Please suggest some really good books which I could buy.

My current knowledge on these technologies - Close to Zero.

Thanks in advance,
Rahul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally like Rebecca Murphey's [jQuery Fundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/book/book.html).

Other great (free) online resources:

- [Mozilla Developer Network's JavaScript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference) — Might as well make this your homepage.
- [jQuery's Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/)
- [MDN's JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide)
- [W3School's JavaScript Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_intro.asp)

I had a friend recently ask me whether it was better to learn unadulterated JavaScript before beginning to use jQuery. After some thought, I decided it wasn't entirely necessary. jQuery just enhances javascript and makes it easier to use, and it'll always be around, so why get into `document.getElementById()` when you'll always have access to jQuery's selector engine? I suppose it's akin to learning math via a calculator, but if you're just looking to write some awesome webapps, you needn't be a JavaScript-amatician.

Also note: JavaScript is sort of a vague term. According to StackOverflow's wiki:

> JavaScript is the common name for ECMAScript, and the name of Mozilla's implementation of ECMAScript. ECMAScript was developed as a standardization of a common subset of features of Mozilla's JavaScript and similar languages.

In layman's terms, this means that JavaScript is a *dialect* of *ECMAScript*. This is sort of convolutes things. Basically, Mozilla developed the JavaScript language, and Microsoft developed JScript to compete (and for compatibility issues). The two were reconciled into the `ECMAScript` standard. So, a body of people publish a standard, then it's up to the developers of the [JavaScript Engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine) to implement them to standard.

Hence, no JavaScript engine is the same (damn you, IE). This is also why you will be hard-pressed to find a definitive JavaScript reference. [Mozilla's Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference) has come up with about as complete a reference as you can find.

Comment: I would argue (foolishly, as I've not consumed all possibilities) that there is no better resource than jQuery Fundamentals. The online format leaves you much more likely to actually complete the exercises in the book (due to proximity to the console), and she approaches things from a standpoint of writing optimized, high-quality JS, whereas a lot of jQuery-focued tutorials will just teach you how to do neat things, performance and best practices be damned.

Answer (score 6):

Rahul,

Most books on JQuery seem to assume some working knowledge of Javascript on the reader's part.

You say that your knowledge on both Javascript AND JQuery are near zero.

I would recommend starting with an introductory book on Javascript like, "JavaScript in 10 Simple Steps or Less".   A basic book like that can help bootstrap you quickly into a working understanding of Javascript.  Enough so that moving on to something like "Beginning Javascript and CSS Development with JQuery" becomes understandable and useful.

Of course, read the JQuery blogs (Remy Sharp has great info!!) or take tutorials at Lynda.com (Dori Smith's Javascript courses are the best!).

Oh... and make sure JQuery and Javascript are on your "interesting tags" list on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

One book on jQuery i find good and interesting is jQuery in Action. If you want to read javascript you should follow javascript.crockford.com

Answer (score 2):

This is the book we have in our libary , many said its nice.

[http://www.amazon.com/Learning-jQuery-1-3-Jonathan-Chaffer/dp/1847196705/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1287891372&sr=1-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847196705)

If you have internet all the time , the below link from jquery is pretty good

http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Comment: I found the tutorials at jquery.com surprisingly poorly thought through and poorly written.

Comment: now a days stackoverflow became like a reference to me , whenever i get stuck or couldn't debug anymore , i post it here and i get the answer in few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Not a book, but this is an outstanding (and free) website:  http://www.learningjquery.com/

Answer (score -1):

There are a few excellent JavaScript books for various levels.

[image]

Comment: Recommendation requests for off-site resources or tools are off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you answer them, you specifically reinforce the belief that Stack Overflow is a good place to answer those questions. It is not. Please don't answer these questions even if you know a good answer as most answers will be highly opinionated ("I personally like..."). You can open the flag dialogue on the question and see the close reason in full under the **off-topic** category, or in the [help/on-topic]. You should also not even answer in a comment, as the effect is similar to an actual answer.